# angular 2 retrieving a token form an api

Tags: javascript, angular

### service.ts

This is my service class. I want to request for a token from an API and display it in my console window. Where am I going wrong, the token is not being displayed. May some please help. Thanks

Apart from the token I will want to retrieve some JSON data but first I want to sort out the token.

```
import {Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions} from '@angular/http';


import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';


@Injectable()

export class StartPage{


    constructor(public http: Http){}


    credential() {
    const url = 'https://xxx';
    const body =  {
    "client_id": 'xxx',
    "client_secret": 'xxx',
    "grant_type": "client_credentials",
    "scope": "transportapi:all"
};

let formData: FormData = new FormData();
            for (let key in body) {

    formData.append(key, body[key]);
}
    const headers = new Headers(
        {
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        });
    return this.http.post(url, formData, {headers: headers});
}



}
```

### app.component

This is my component class. I want to get a token from an API but the token is not being displayed.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

import {StartPage} from '../app/service';



@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Hello results {{results.access_token}}</h1>'
    ,
    providers: [StartPage]

})

export class AppComponent{

  results:String;
  public testing:{};


    constructor(public service: StartPage){


    }

   onSubmit(){

    this.service.credential().subscribe(
        res => {
            this.results = res['access_token'];
            console.log(this.results)
        }
    );



}


}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I  am basically not getting any display. As you can see in my component template  '<h1>Hello results {{results.access_token}}</h1>'  I want to display the token. But only the Hello is displaying

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring 'results:String', so when you set an object (res['access_token']) is been saved as string....

Try declaring results as any ('results:any')